# Finding the location (line, column) of a field value in a JSON file

Tags: json, jq

Consider the following JSON file *example.json*:

```
{
    "key1": ["arr value 1", "arr value 2", "arr value 3"],
    "key2": {
        "key2_1": ["a1", "a2"],
        "key2_2": {
            "key2_2_1": 1.43123123,
            "key2_2_2": 456.3123,
            "key2_2_3": "string1"
        }
    }
}
```

The following `jq` command extracts a value from the above file:

```
jq ".key2.key2_2.key2_2_1" example.json
```

Output:

```
1.43123123
```

Is there an option in `jq` that, instead of printing the value itself, prints the location (line and column, start and end position) of the value within a (valid) JSON file, given an *Object Identifier-Index* (`.key2.key2_2.key2_2_1` in the example)?

The output could be something like:

```
some_utility ".key2.key2_2.key2_2_1" example.json
```

Output:

```
(6,25) (6,35)
```

Comment: Not in Python. It parses the JSON into lists and dictionaries, with no information about the original JSON layout.

Comment: I doubt `jq` can do it, either.

Comment: A quick hack with awk to get the start position (assumes the value is on one line and not repeated): `jq ".key2.key2_2.key2_2_1" example.json |awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} {for (i in a) {if (p=index($0, i)) print NR "," p} }' - example.json`

Comment: Here's a quick but pure `jq` solution with some rough edges, outputting 0-based values:  `jq -Rrs '"\(fromjson.key2.key2_2.key2_2_1)" as $query | ($query | length) as $length | ./"\n" | to_entries[] | {row: .key, col: .value | indices($query)[]} | "(\(.row),\(.col)) (\(.row),\(.col + $length))"'` -> `(5,24) (5,34)` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/c0onai3rrzE)

Comment: @pmf Thank you! this looks really good! If this question hadn't been closed, it might be the accepted answer (after augmenting it with the explanation of how it works).

Comment: I started a thread on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420239/why-was-this-question-flagged-as-out-of-focus) about why this question was flagged as "out of focus".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given JSON data and a query, there is no

> option in `jq` that, instead of printing the value itself, prints the location

of possible matches.

This is because JSON parsers providing an interface to developers usually focus on processing the logical structure of a JSON input, not the textual stream conveying it. You would have to instruct it to explicitly treat its input as raw text, while properly parsing it at the same time in order to extract the queried value. In the case of `jq`, the former can be achieved using the `--raw-input` (or `-R`) option, the latter then by parsing the read-in JSON-encoded string using `fromjson`.

The `-R` option alone would read the input linewise into an array of strings, which would have to be concatenated (e.g. using `add`) in order to provide the whole input at once to `fromjson`. The other way round, you could also provide the `--slurp` (or `-s`) option which (in combination with `-R`) already concatenates the input to a single string which then, after having parsed it with `fromjson`, would have to be split again into lines (e.g. using `/"\n"`) in order to provide row numbers. I found the latter to be more convenient.

That said, this could give you a starting point (the `--raw-output` (or `-r`) option outputs raw text instead of JSON):

```bash
jq -Rrs '
  "\(fromjson.key2.key2_2.key2_2_1)" as $query    # save the query value as string
  | ($query | length) as $length      # save its length by counting its characters
  | ./"\n" | to_entries[]      # split into lines and provide 0-based line numbers
  | {row: .key, col: .value | indices($query)[]}   # find occurrences of the query
  | "(\(.row),\(.col)) (\(.row),\(.col + $length))"            # format the output
'
```

```json
(5,24) (5,34)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/omxgd95n3op)

Now, this works for the sample query, how about the general case? Your example queried a number (`1.43123123`) which is an easy target as it has the same textual representation when encoded as JSON. Therefore, a simple string search and length count did a fairly good job (not a perfect one because it would still find any occurrence of that character stream, not just "values"). Thus, for more precision, but especially with more complex JSON datatypes being queried, you would need to develop a more sophisticated searching approach, probably involving more JSON conversions, whitespace stripping and other normalizing shenanigans. So, unless your goal is to rebuild a full JSON parser within another one, you should narrow it down to the kind of queries you expect, and compose an appropriately tailored searching approach. This solution provides you with concepts to simultaneously process the input textually and structurally, and with a simple search and ouput integration.

Comment: Is it possible to improve it to retrieve the position of an array or object?

Comment: @Berk7871 As I tried to argue, It is possible but the way there might be intricate, and you'd be better off avoiding general cases. The more complex you allow the logical structure queried to be, the more shapes it can assume in its textual representation, and the more cumbersome becomes the task to capture it in an amorphous yet valid JSON input stream.